# Unable to load swast with nvidia-drivers-465

Tags: drivers, nvidia

When trying to load steam it promptly crashes.

Running steam in the terminal this line seems like an issue:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail" Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:6811): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/main.rc:733: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'

(steam:6811): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  52
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  51
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
```

Installing this fixes it:

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-465:i386
```

However it removes: `libnvidia-gl-465 libnvidia-ifr1-465 nvidia-driver-465`

Causing games to be unplayable. (Kinda defeating the point right?)

I encountered this issue trying to get tensorflow working with my gpu (Nvidia 1070) and it is working now but I would also like to play games when not working on machine learning.

`uname -a` returns

```
Linux codedcosmos-UBUNTU 5.8.0-53-generic #60~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 09:52:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

If you can help

Thank you, I appreciate you

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/nr8lnx/unable_to_load_swast_with_nvidiadrivers465/

Comment: My advice: downgrade to nvidia 450. I cannot even make nvidia 460 or nvidia 465 work with Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.8. That seems to be an incompatibility between Nvidia DKMS 460 and the kernel 5.8.

Comment: can you compare the version are the from the packages libnvidia-gl-465:i386 libnvidia-gl-465 are the same?  
`apt-cache policy libnvidia-gl-465:i386 libnvidia-gl-465`

Comment: They don't match how do I force a specific version?

Comment: can you show me the output from my command please? I have no idea where there come from normal ubuntu sources or from a ppa on your system..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps worked for me:

1. Remove nvidia repositories like the developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/...
2. Uninstalling all your nvidia drivers and anything nvidia related
3. Run

   sudo apt update
4. Install your drivers:

   sudo apt install libnvidia-cfg1-465 libnvidia-common-465 libnvidia-common-465 libnvidia-compute-465 libnvidia-decode-465 libnvidia-encode-465 libnvidia-extra-465 libnvidia-fbc1-465 libnvidia-gl-465 libnvidia-ifr1-465 nvidia-compute-utils-465 nvidia-dkms-465 nvidia-driver-465 nvidia-kernel-common-465 nvidia-kernel-source-465 nvidia-utils-465 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-465 libnvidia-gl-465:i386

Installing nvidia drivers,
5. Follow the steps on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu to install stuff required for tensorflow-gpu.